# Scrollable content inside stack

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[image]

I want to build like this UI, but i want to show the below cards to the right of the first one. i want to make the cards scrollable, so when the user swipe to the right the below card will replace the first one and vice versa.

Comment: take a look at this package:  https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_swiper

Comment: Looks awesome man, thnx a lot (: